# Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10-release-894. Help me out someone?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

A problem occurred configuring root project 'Dice Roller'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.A problem occurred configuring root project 'Dice Roller'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10-release-894.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.10-release-894/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.10-release-894.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.10-release-894/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.10-release-894.pom
> Required by:
> project :

Possible solution:

- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

  > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10-release-894.
  > Searched in the following locations:
  > - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.10-release-894/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.10-release-894.pom
  > - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.10-release-894/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.10-release-894.pom
  > Required by:
  > project :

Possible solution:

- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

on top level

build.gradle

replace it with a static version number

```
dependencies 
{
 
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10"

    }
```

Comment: doesn't work for me, any other solution? I get a timeout error, even in Tools>Kotlin>Configuration when I am trying to get updates it can't be done and I get a timeout error